# specifying conditions as a variable to assign values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe to which I would like to assign percentages and reasons based on conditions:

```
attach(df)
df$profile[ColumnX>=0.5, ColumnY == 2]<-"Profile 1"
df$prediction[ColumnX>=0.5, ColumnY == 2]<-0.84
df$reason[ColumnX>=0.5, ColumnY == 2]<-"Reason 1"
detach(df)
```

Can I avoid the duplication by using a variable for "ColumnX>=0.5, ColumnY == 2"?

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
var <- expression(ColumnX>=0.5, ColumnY == 2)
attach(df)
df$profile[eval(var)]<-"Profile 1"
df$prediction[eval(var)]<-0.84
df$reason[eval(var)]<-"Reason 1"
detach(df)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a logical vector with your condition, and then subset based on this.

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(X=runif(100), Y=sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE))

# create a logical vector with the conditions
var <- df$X >= 0.5 & df$Y == 2

# assign new values
df$profile[var] <- "Profile1"
df$prediction[var] <- 0.84
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the logical condition `ColumnX>=0.5, ColumnY == 2`, and use the values to fill the new columns.

**Solution**

Make use of `dplyr::mutate` to create the result in one call:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, 
       cond = ColumnX >= 0.5 & ColumnY == 2, 
       profile = ifelse(cond, "Profile 1", NA), 
       prediction = ifelse(cond, 0.84, NA), 
       reason = ifelse(cond, "Reason 1", NA),
       cond = NULL)
```

**Some more information**

- It will also work with the `base::transform` function, but needs three instead of one step, to generate the `cond`ition column first, generate the new columns `profile`, `prediction` and `results`, and then drop `cond` again.
- Instead of `ifelse` you can also use `factor`, e.g:

  ```
  factor(cond, labels = c("Profile 1", NA))
  ```